# how to draw vertical line dynamically?

Tags: android

I want a vertical line drawn dynamically inside the a table row. Some thing like below in XML:

I was able to get all the layout from code, except the "View". Any suggestion would be appreciated!

```
<TableRow>
   <LinearLayout 
     ......
     android:orientation="vertical">
     <CheckBox>..</CheckBox>
     <Button>..</Button>
  </LinearLayout>

  <View   // this is what I want to achieve, dynamically
    android:layout_width="2dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FAFFFB"/>

</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
View view = new View(this);
view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(2,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
layout.add(view);
```